# Not able to change order status in hook "woocommerce_new_order"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce, orders

After paying with Stripe via SEPA at WooCommerce and an incorrect IBAN is specified, the customer will see an error message in the checkout area that the IBAN is incorrect. WooCommerce still creates an order and sets the status to Pending.

I use a snippet to query whether an order has a transaction ID. If no ID is present, the status is set to Aborted. This also works, but at the same moment WooCommerce automatically changes this status back to Pending.

```php
function cancel_order_stripe( $order_id ) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $trans_code = $order->get_transaction_id();
    $pay_methos = $order->get_payment_method();

    if (empty($trans_code)){
        $order->update_status('failed', 'Bestellung wurde vom System abgebrochen.');
        $order->save;
    }
    //var_dump($order);
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'cancel_order_stripe',  10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very probably that the payment gateway is overriding the status that you're setting. The `woocommerce_new_order` hook is indeed called upon order creation, but shortly after creation, the order is sent off to the payment gateway for handling.

Certain gateways immediately set the status as they require manual processing, for instance.

You've got a few options to work around this:

1. The `woocommerce_update_order` action hook is called after every save action

```php
function action_woocommerce_update_order( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Finds whether a variable is null
    $order = is_null( $order ) ? wc_get_order( $order_id ) : $order;
    
    $trans_code = $order->get_transaction_id();
    // Etc...
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'action_woocommerce_update_order', 10, 2 );
```

---

2. The `woocommerce_payment_successful_result` filter hook is called after a successful payment

```php
function filter_woocommerce_payment_successful_result( $result, $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $trans_code = $order->get_transaction_id();
        // Etc...
    }

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', 'filter_woocommerce_payment_successful_result', 10, 2 );
```

---

3. The `woocommerce_payment_complete` action hook is called when a payment is complete with a valid status

```php
function action_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $trans_code = $order->get_transaction_id();
        // Etc...
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_woocommerce_payment_complete', 10, 1 );
```

---

Source: [Not able to change status in hook "woocommerce_new_order" #25964](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/25964#issuecomment-601803921)

Comment: After I only do it via a variable, no more entries are made in the logs, but the checkout page loads indefinitely

Comment: @OnyxDev If so, you should see the reason why in your log files. See the link (how to debug) I referenced earlier. It's pretty pointless to post comment thats something doesn't work for you specifically when it generally works. In other words. You are doing something wrong or there is an issue with your specific setup versus a general one